# How do i design a composite view and view model using Silverlight and MVVM?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I want to create a "Wizard" in my Silverlight MVVM application. The Wizard should contain multiple steps between which you can navigate using "next" and "previous".
The problem I am facing is the relationship between views and view models. 
I want there to be a view and view model for the Wizard itself. My instinct tells me that there should be one view/view model pair for each step in the wizard.

What is a good approach for maintaining these kinds of relationships, where one view model holds several other view models and the view actually consists of several smaller views?
Are there any patterns or practices that I can use?

I know this question might be subjective, but give me the rough cuts of an approach and I'll award you an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd propose main wizard viewModel which has a collection of `steps` view models and handles navigation between them. While navigating it should call validation methods in `step` viewModels:

WizardVM:

```
public class WizardVM
{
     // this commands should support CanExecute
     public ICommand GotoNextCommand { get; private set; } // should open next step VM
     public ICommand GotoBackCommand { get; private set; } // should open previous step VM

     // this prop should be set by 'GotoNext', 'GotoBack' commands
     public object CurrentStep { get; private set; }

     // probably internally you will have a list of all steps:
     private ICollection<object> _stepViewModels = ...;
}
```

WizardView:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentStep}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Command="{Binding GotoBackCommand}">Back</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding GotoNextCommand}">Next</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

**UPDATE**:

Views can be coupled with ViewModels via `Datatemplating`. For example add this into resources in `App.Xaml`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Step1ViewModel}">
     <Step1View />
</DateTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Step2ViewModel}">
     <Step2View />
</DateTemplate>
```

Your viewModels should know absolutely nothing about views. It means that `WizardVM` should 
expose only other viewModels but not views. It's a rule of thumb for MVVM.

**UPDATE2** Oops, I forgot that Silverlight doesn't have DataTemplating yet. In silverlight I would still expose ViewModels but bind them to `ContentPresenters` using a converter which will convert a viewModel into corresponding view.

Comment: Wow that was quick!
But... i am curious, do you think that the CurrentStep property should be something visible (I.E a view)? Otherwise I don't see how the ContentPresenter would render it. My problem is to hook up the containing views and viewmodels with eachother.

Comment: @Per, `CurrentStep` should expose Step ViewModel. See updated answer

Comment: Ok... using a value converter to convert a viewmodel into a view. That's quite manipulative, ehrm.. I mean pragmatic :) But nevertheless, a fresh approach I did not expect! I doubt this is what I'll go for, but I am going to award you the answer for beeing innovative even beyond my own (rather manipulative) nature... Thanks for taking the time to respond!