# Multiple steps dictated by a MVVM ViewModel: Best practices?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

Imagine having a View which will show multiple steps of data gathering. Based on decisions in the previous step, the sequence or specific instances of the following steps will vary.

Following MVVM purist best practices, I figure having a list of ViewModels in the outer ViewModel is the way to go about this, and let the outer View bind a custom tab control (or similar) to that.

This brings me to two aspects of this which are unclear to me:

**Point One: "Which came first?"**

The outer View / ViewModel combo would probably be "View First". That is, a view either receives a ViewModel, or instantiates one.

But when it comes to the list of ViewModels within this outer ViewModel: Where do their respective Views come from? Which entity is responsible for picking the best view for each of these?

I'm not all comfortable with alternating between "View First" and "ViewModel First" like this.

**Point Two: Communication between ViewModels**

When one of the inner ViewModel steps are completed, e.g. at the click of a "Save" or "Next" button, a command should be fired to that inner ViewModel, and then the next should be shown.

This requires the outer ViewModel to:

1. be able to pick up on the Save command sent to the inner ViewModel
2. be able to access the data within the inner ViewModel.

How would one normally go about this? Is it considered a bad practice to tie the inner and outer ViewModel together with events?

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160829/how-do-i-design-a-composite-view-and-view-model-using-silverlight-and-mvvm), this question has some related information

Comment: View First is only one correct approach, because passing a view to a view model violates principles of MVVM. Corresponding views are applied in xaml like '<view:SomeView DataContext="{Binding SomeInnerViewModel}" />'. For communication use the Messenger class from the MvvmLight library.

Comment: I use [a DI library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and pick the views and view models in its mappings, binding things together in top-level "module" code.  But my apps have never been that complicated.  This doesn't solve your sub-view problem either.  Things like the Prism [Region feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions(v=pandp.40).aspx) might help with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) In my understanding `MVVM` always says `ViewModels first` and `Views` are bound to already instantiated `ViewModels`. For all inner/outer ViewModels.

> Where do their respective Views come from? Which entity is responsible for picking the best view for each of these?

In WPF I prefer to use `DataTemplating` for this reason. In `app.xaml` or some other application-wide resource file you define `DataTemplates` specific to each of your ViewModels. In `Views` you put a binding to ViewModel into `ContentPresenter` and DataTemplating bring View there. Sample:

**App.xaml**:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:OuterViewModel}">
        <local:OuterView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:InnerViewModel}">
        <local:InnerView />
    </DataTemplate>
<Application.Resources>
```

**OuterView.xaml**:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Assuming OuterViewModel has a property named 'InnerViewModel' -->
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding InnerViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

2)

> be able to pick up on the Save command sent to the inner ViewModel

I would put `SaveCommand` on `OuterViewModel`

> be able to access the data within the inner ViewModel.

I would have a reference to each inner ViewModel in OuterViewModel